# Custom nonlinear function in `R.gnm`

Tags: r, regression, non-linear-regression

I'm trying to build a nonlinear model as described in [the manual for gmn in R](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/gnm/vignettes/gnmOverview.pdf).  The desired form of the model is

```
y = b0*x0^g0 + b1*x1^g1 + ...
```

This would seem to be the simplest possible form of nonlinear model to me, but for some reason (and please correct me if I'm wrong!) I have to write a custom nonlinear function to fit it in R.  Very well!

```
df=read.csv("d:/mydataframe.csv")
require(gnm)

mypower = function(x){
  list(predictors = list(beta=1,gamma=1),
       variables = list(substitute(x)),
       term = function(predlabels,varlabels) {
       paste(predlabels[1],"*(",varlabels[1],"**",predlabels[2],")")
       }
  )
}
class(mypower) <- "nonlin"
```

Now when I try

```
fit <- gnm(formula=y ~ mypower(x1), data=df)
```

I get a fitted value of beta and gamma from the model.  But when I try

```
fit <- gnm(formula=y ~ mypower(x1)+mypower(x2), data=df)
```

I get the error

```
Algorithm failed - no model could be estimated.
```

So, question 1: how can I solve this?

Also, when - trying to match all xs - I try

```
fit <- gnm(formula=PedalCycles ~ mypower(.), data=df)
```

I get

```
Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object '.' not found
```

Is this the right way to specify a sum of all xs each raised to a power?

Answer (score 3):

To estimate `y = b_0*x_0^g_0` you could use gnm's built-in `Exp()` to estimate

```
Exp( 1 + I( log(x_0) ) )
```

This gives you coefficients:

1. `b'_0` for the intercept
2. `g'_0` for `log(x_0)`

Hence `g'_0` is your desired `g_0` (since `e^log(x_0)*g'_0 = x_0^g_0`) and `e^b'_0` is `b_0`. Your model is now a sum of such terms.

**Caveat:** This will *not* work if `x_0` assumes non-positive values in your data set.